# Preheader in SFMC has a known bug when it comes to using ampscript, but

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

For SFMC there exists this known bug: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321251&type=1

I understand how to handle it, putting things above the body-tag, but now I have a preheader that's called from a Data Extension with a variable:

[image: example]

And I need this because it can contain different languages.
But in that different languages i use the recurring name of a store and that name is also in a variable.

When rendering, the preheader shows with the storename, but the storename disappears in the inbox, just like the bug describes - except that it's sort of an inception thingy, with a variable in a variable.

I've tried using treatascontent() but to no avail.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! +1 for the "Inception" reference/illustration. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are specifically asking for a workaround - use inline AMPscript in the preheader. If that gets messy, you can also use `%%=ContentBlockByKey('SomeContentBlockCustomerKey')=%%` in the preheader, put all your logic into that content block and the contained AMPScript should render at the right time.

Comment: I've used this workaround successfully before but for some reason I can't manage to get this to work again. I put the exact inline AMPScript in the preheader section (in the UI) with all my code in the referenced content block. I tried a code snippet and a html block but it doesn't make a difference. It looks like all variables are "forgotten" after the preheader, when I try to reference them in the subject and in the body no variables render. Any pointers you can give that might cause this?